# tensorflow confusion matrix in Experimenter during evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, confusion-matrix

I've got some troubles during the model evaluation using Tensorflow with the Experimenter API.

I used to work using 2-classes NN, but this time I manage to train a 4-classes one and I need to figure out how to build a confusion matrix in this case. I tried using the `tf.confusion_matrix` function, but it doesn't work at all.

This is the fragment of code that I used:

```
if mode == ModeKeys.EVAL:

    eval_metric_ops = {
        'accuracy' : metrics.streaming_accuracy(predictions=predicted_classes, labels=labels),

        # Other metrics...

        'confusion_matrix': tf.confusion_matrix(prediction=predicted_classes, label=labels, num_classes=4)
    }

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predicted_classes,
        loss=loss,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops
    )
```

And this is the error that I got:

```
TypeError: Values of eval_metric_ops must be (metric_value, update_op) tuples, given: (<tf.Operation 'test/group_deps' type=NoOp>, <tf.Tensor 'test/accuracy/value:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'test/confusion:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=int32_ref>) for key: confusion_matrix
```

I read other answers about to create a confusion matrix in Tensorflow and I understood how to do it, but I think that my question is more related to the Estimator/Experimenter API.

Comment: I am having the same question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your codes doesn't work because the framework expects eval_metric_ops to be a dictionary containing key with the name of the operation and values of type tuple (result tensor, update_operation for this tensor)

tf.confusion_matrix(prediction=predicted_classes, label=labels, num_classes=4) only returns the expected tensor.

You have to implement your own metric operation like this:

> ```
> def eval_confusion_matrix(labels, predictions):
>     with tf.variable_scope("eval_confusion_matrix"):
>         con_matrix = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=labels, predictions=predictions, num_classes=4)
>
>         con_matrix_sum = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(4,4), dtype=tf.int32),
>                                             trainable=False,
>                                             name="confusion_matrix_result",
>                                             collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
>
>
>         update_op = tf.assign_add(con_matrix_sum, con_matrix)
>
>         return tf.convert_to_tensor(con_matrix_sum), update_op
>
>
>
> # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
> eval_metric_ops = {
>     "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predicted_classes),
>     "conv_matrix": eval_confusion_matrix(
>         labels, predicted_classes)
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please use either tf.metrics.* or tf.contrib.metrics.* for metric calculation. There are subtle things to write a currect metric behavior.
There are some utilities in tf.contrib.metrics, such as streaming_true_positives which you may find useful.

Comment: I know, but `streaming_true_positives` is not really useful if you have 4 classes, because it shows only the overall true positives.